# Javascript bug on array.pop()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that includes some sub arrays, and the sub arrays contain some objects, which looks something like this (4 sub-arrays and first 3 sub-arrays have completely identical content).

```
let mainArray = [
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    },
    {
      'key2' : 'value2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    },
    {
      'key2' : 'value2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    },
    {
      'key2' : 'value2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    }
  ]
]
```

now I want to use Array.pop() to get rid of the last object of the first sub-array `key2 : value2` , which should leads to something like this.

```
let mainArray = [
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    },
    {
      'key2' : 'value2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    },
    {
      'key2' : 'value2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    }
  ]
]
```

However, when I tried to run testArray[0].pop(), it affects not only [0], but also [1] and [2], which is something like this.

```
let mainArray = [
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      'key1' : 'value1'
    }
  ]
]
```

I tried it on https://jsfiddle.net/vbp02Lmk/4/ and it works perfectly but when I use it on my work, it tries to pop everything identical..

p.s the code I wrote for my work is also `mainArray[0].pop()` , and the only difference is that the sub-arrays for my work contains a bigger object with more keys and values.

Much appreciated if someone could tell me what did I do wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see `key3 : value` in your first subarray

Comment: check `mainArray[0] == mainArray[1]` or something like that.

Comment: It seems you are have create a sub array and pushed it 3 times to create three identical array. Is it so?

Comment: Here's a fiddle that reproduces your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3w68ukh7/ This is how programming languages handle variables: as references  to memory locations. If you push the same memory object to some other array multiple times, then call pop on it, all of its occurrences elsewhere are affected. If you don't want this, you need to clone the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably inserting the same `object` multiple times in your local work. They all have the same **reference** so if you delete something in the first `sub-array` it will change it for all. Because all sub-arrays in your array are basically the same object with the same reference.

Check the snippet for an example (Mind that the output of the snippet already hints that it references the same object):

```js
let elem = [{'key1' : 'value1'}, {'key2' : 'value2'}]

let arr = []

arr.push(elem)
arr.push(elem)
arr.push(elem)
arr.push(elem)

console.log(arr)

arr[0].pop()

console.log(arr)
```

And here a example without the same reference problem:

```js
let elem1 = [{'key1' : 'value1'}, {'key2' : 'value2'}]
let elem2 = [{'key1' : 'value1'}, {'key2' : 'value2'}]
let elem3 = [{'key1' : 'value1'}, {'key2' : 'value2'}]
let elem4 = [{'key1' : 'value1'}, {'key2' : 'value2'}]

let arr = []

arr.push(elem1)
arr.push(elem2)
arr.push(elem3)
arr.push(elem4)

console.log(arr)

arr[0].pop()

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation!
I cloned the subarray first before putting inside the main array and `.pop()` works perfectly!